# NSDateFormatter confused by 24-hour time

Tags: ios, json, timezone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am building an app which will rely on a server with a SQL database. The database automatically stores timestamps that look like:

```
2013-04-26 22:56:05
```

I have a URL on my server with a PHP file that gets the data and `echo`s it back to the app as JSON.

When the app gets the data, the timestamp is still the same - `timestamp = "2013-04-26 22:56:05";`

```
NSString *timestamp = [mArray[1] objectForKey:@"timestamp"];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"EDT"]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:timestamp];
NSLog(@"NSDATE: %@", date);
```

And it comes out as: `NSDATE: 2013-04-27 04:56:05 +0000`. Which obviously isn't the same.

My server is a Linux box in North Virginia (EDT), I'm on MDT.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSDate and NSDateFormatter magic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135147/nsdate-and-nsdateformatter-magic)

Comment: Actually, I think I misread your issue. I thought you were talking about the 24-hour time setting in the Settings app. When you log an `NSDate`, the date is always shown in UTC time. Your two dates are the same. This time of year MDT is UTC -6 hours. So 22:56 MDT is 04:56 the next day UTC. All is as expected. Though this doesn't explain it perfectly since EDT is UTC -4 and you seem to be using EDT, not MDT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

My server was on UTC time! I changed

```
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"EDT"]];
```

to

```
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
```

and now it works as expected.